# Communication between Intel Edison and Open Mv7

Tags: serial, communication

I'm trying to do a simple communication between an Intel Edison and Open Mv 7 Camera through UART (Tx/Rx). I assumed this would be a simple task but both sides receive "�". Both are using python, the Intel Edison using  Pyserial to communicate while OpenMv7 is using PYB library.

Open Mv7.

```
import time
from pyb import UART

uart = UART(3, 9600)


while(True):
    if(uart.any() > 0):
        print(uart.read())
```

Intel Edison

```
import serial
import time 

ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600)
ser.close()
ser.open()

print("Online")

ser.write("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the code should work. I can suggest 3 things that might be of assistance.

1. Make sure you have a prominent Common Ground Sometimes your PC isn't enough
2. Increase the BraudRate on both devices.
3. Most important make sure both devices are running at the same voltage. The Intel Edison is 1.8V without the Arduino Expander and the Arduino expander has a jumper that allows it to work at both 3.3V and 5V. You might need to switch it to 5V.

Comment: Signal ground should be part of the serial cable, and baud rate shouldn't matter as long as it is the same on both ends. Ensuring the voltages are the same both ends is important however.